# Issue with Angular js application on IE9 (Windows 7) while it is working fine on IE9 (Windows 8.1)

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, windows-8.1

I am using windows 8.1, Internet Explorer 11. As I need to make my angularjs application working on IE9, I have simulated IE9 on windows 8.1 using IE browser settings and made relevant changes to my angularjs code to make it work on IE9. Finally I succeeded and the application is running fine (Windows 8.1, IE9)  as shown in the image and you can find the simulated browser IE9 settings too.

[image: using ie9 on Windows 8.1]

Before moving to production, I thought of testing my application on real IE9. So I have used another system which has Windows 7 with IE9. But when I access my application on IE9 from windows 7 system, the application is not all loading and is giving so many errors. From the console errors I realized none of my included js files are being processed correctly. Please find the screen shot of it (this is from IE9 on windows 7). I could not able to figure out what is the cause of the issue and  its fix. Any guidelines please ...

[image: using IE9 on Windows 7]

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this issue is by default in Windows 7, IE9 Document mode Quirks is getting selected, when I set it to Internet Explorer 9 standard every thing is working fine even on windows 7 IE9. The following code snippet in head tag of jsp page solves the issue too.

```
<meta charset="utf-8"  http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />
```